# Como usar ssl com php?

Tags: php, ssl

Vou comprar uma certificação *SSL* para meu site, porém, ainda não estou entendendo muito bem como funciona. A única coisa que tenho que fazer para que o site fique "seguro", é adicionar "https" nas *URLs*, ou tenho que mudar alguma coisa no código *php*?

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: No PHP não, no Apache/NGINX sim, você precisa importar a chave privada e pública para o servidor, num local seguro, não acessível ao público. Depois indicar o `ssl_certificate` e `ssl_certificate_key`. Não respondo sua pergunta porque não especifica qual servidor está utilizando (apache, nginx.....) e nem se tem acesso a tais configurações.

Comment: @Inkeliz utilizo apache e tenho acesso as configurações.

Comment: Também não especificou o SO que está usando. O ambiente e a forma mudam a depender do SO.

Answer (score 1):

No Apache, basta adicionar (criar um novo `VirtualHost`):

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /caminho/para/seu_site_certificado.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /caminho/para/sua_chave_privada.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /caminho/para/seu_certificado_intermediario.crt
```

*Normalmente este arquivo está em `/etc/httpd/` (no caso de CentOS, por exemplo) ou `/etc/apache2/` (no caso do Ubuntu, por exemplo).*

Explicando cada recurso:

- `SSLCertificateFile`: Define o caminho do seu certificado (normalmente nomeado como `meusite_com_br.crt`, ou similar).
- `SSLCertificateKeyFile`: Define o caminho da chave privada (normalmente nomeado com a extensão `.key`, mas essa é que você quem gera utilizando o `openssl` por exemplo, para obter o `.csr`).
- `SSLCertificateChainFile`: Define o caminho para o CA-Bundle (normalmente nomeado como `comodo.crt` no caso de apenas o *intermediário* ou `seusite_com_br.ca-bundle` no caso de haver o *root* e o *intermediário*).

---

Além disso deverá de aceitar conexão na porta `443` ao invés da `80`, por exemplo:

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:443>
```

Se utilizar `:80` não irá funcionar, não se esqueça de abrir a porta `443` no firewall, caso por algum motivo desligue *todas as portas*.

---

No final terá algo assim:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
   DocumentRoot /local/do/html
   ServerName exemplo.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
   DocumentRoot /local/do/html
   ServerName exemplo.com
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /crt/exemplo_com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /crt/exemplo_com.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /crt/exemplo_com.ca-bundle

   SSLOptions +StrictRequire
   SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
   SSLCompression off
</VirtualHost>
```

O `SSLOptions +StrictRequire`, `SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2` e o `SSLCompression off` são opcionais, porém recomendo utilizar. O primeiro irá proibir de se conectar se não for conectado usando HTTPS, em resumo. O segundo irá desabilitar o `SSL` e vai habilitar o `TLS`, `TLS 1.1` e o `TLS 1.2`, o `SSLv2` é vulnerável e o `SSLv3` tem o bug do [POODLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE), por isso ambos estão desligados pelo `-all`. O `SSLCompression off` é para evitar o problema de [CRIME attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME_(security_exploit)).

---

No PHP nenhuma mudança é necessária, exceto renomear os links de `http://` para `https://`, se houver necessidade disso ser feito. Além disso pode criar um redirecionamento de `http://` para o `https://`, afim de que todas as conexões passam a ser sobre o SSL/TLS.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Inkeliz